# Starting events in JQM

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

How to start events in jqm? I made a script which never fires on Android device, but it works on chrome web browser. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem surely is not putting your script in right place. If you want event connected with page to work, you should place it in  nodes.